# VBA copy sheet and rename error

Tags: vba, excel

I have a piece of code where i don't see where it goes wrong exactly.
I have this macro that copies a sheet a certain amount of times and name them "Sheet" + number.

```
 'copies over template to amount of items
    For numtimes = 2 To LastRow
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet").Copy _
    After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet")
    'test voor name copy
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet" & i
    Next
```

when i run this it copies the sheet only two times. One named "Sheet2"(as it should), but one as "Sheet (2)", and an error that the name is already taken.
I don't really see where it goes wrong, or why it half works.

Comment: Your `i` doesn't change in coping loop. Should be `numtimes` probably.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't appear to be increasing `i`?

Perhaps you could just use `numtimes`?

```
For numtimes = 2 To LastRow
   ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheet").Copy _
   After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet")
   'test voor name copy
   ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet" & numtimes 
Next
```

Comment: ohw duh, i can't believe i looked over that. thanks!

Comment: `Option Explicit` *might* have helped you with this one - but as I can't see all the code I've no idea if `i` was ever declared.